# py-bcrypt fails to load

Tags: python, virtualenv, wsgi

I have py-bcrypt installed in my virtualenv, but I can't get it to load the libraries in the virtualenv when the app is run through WSGI.

```
python /var/www/api-test/api.wsgi
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/api-test/api.wsgi", line 3, in <module>
    from api import app as application
  File "/var/www/api-test/api.py", line 5, in <module>
    import os, hashlib, bcrypt
ImportError: No module named bcrypt
```

However, running python and loading the library manually works fine

```
python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Mar 13 2014, 11:03:55) 
[GCC 4.7.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import bcrypt
>>> bcrypt
<module 'bcrypt' from '/var/www/api-test/api-env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/bcrypt/__init__.pyc'>
>>>
```

Comment: Are you sure that you using python from virtualenv?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I needed to add the following to my api.wsgi file:

```
import site
site.addsitedir("/var/www/api-test/api-env/lib/python2.7/site-packages")
```